# Geoprocessing service to import CAD file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, modelbuilder, geoprocessing-service

I need to publish a geoprocessing service to import CAD file in a Web AppBuilder application and add it as a map service.

1. I tried to use ModelBuilder using the `CAD to Geodatabase tool`
2. Made the `input cad` as model parameter
3. Passed the output to the `CAD to Geodatabase tool`

But I can't pass the copy output to the `CAD to Geodatabase tool`
otherwise the input file will be a static file not from a user upload

[image]

I got this methodology as referenced [in this GeoNet post](https://community.esri.com/thread/184132-cad-in-geoprocessing-service).

I tried the tool the person attached but it has its own errors and couldn't resolve due to my lack of Python knowledge.

Comment: Why are you doing a copy?  The image you posted does not show the model as having any parameters.

Comment: i'm copying as the " CAD to geodatabase " doesn't accept the file as user input, or i'm unable to make it, i can only be a parameter with the copy tool
sorry for not being a parameter in the image but i can't make the " cad " tool to accept a user input either ways, it works without the copy tool but the file is predefined when you utilize the geoprocessing service, i need to make the user upload the file by himself, i hope it's more clear